Springdoc: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.LiteWebJarsResourceResolver
I've just upgraded springdoc from version 2.6.0 to 2.7.0 (nothing else was changed) and now I get a
ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.LiteWebJarsResourceResolver

I'm running on Spring: 6.1.14 and SB: 3.3.5.
Any Idea how to fix this issue?
Kind regards, Daniel

Hmmm, maybe springdoc: 2.7.0 depends on sring: 6.2.x?
As the LiteWebJarsResourceResolver was only introduced in 6.2.

Full Stacktrace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4d065e1a testClass = cofee.controller.CrewMemberControllerTest, locations = [], classes = [cofee.CofeeApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["junit", "cdsmock"], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1a245833, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5b799640, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@194fad1, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@790da477, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@55de24cc, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizerFactory$OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizer@69c81773, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@5c86a017, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@6e5c6e5c], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.springWebProvider
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:789)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:607)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@639fee48]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:750)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/LiteWebJarsResourceResolver
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.LiteWebJarsResourceResolver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 69 more


Yes - springdoc: 2.7.0 is only compatible with
SpringBoot 3.4.x
see here: compatibility-matrix

Please stop confusing the public. Below's the compabitlity matrix:



Spring Framework
Spring Boot
Springdoc




6.2.0
3.4.x
2.7.x


6.1.15
3.3.6
2.6.x




Not entirely sure why YOU are being confused, but thanks for confirming my answer.
